# Jitsi in react native - video conferencing

Tags: react-native, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I want to use Jitsi-meet in react native for video conferencing what is the best method for implementation.
Currently I am following this link https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/intro
But in this they have used native code for android and iOS
Can someone please suggest me how should I proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is the documentation of the jitsi native SDK. If you want to implement this SDK in a react-native project, you should have a look at [react-native-jitsi-meet](https://github.com/skrafft/react-native-jitsi-meet) plugin.

As you can read in the documentation of the plugin, just install the plugin, and you will be able to initiate calls with your room url :

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const url = 'https://your.jitsi.server/roomName'; // can also be only room name and will connect to jitsi meet servers
      const userInfo = { displayName: 'User', email: 'user@example.com', avatar: 'https:/gravatar.com/avatar/abc123' };
      JitsiMeet.call(url, userInfo);
      /* You can also use JitsiMeet.audioCall(url) for audio only call */
      /* You can programmatically end the call with JitsiMeet.endCall() */
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: I have implemented the react-native-jitsi-meet library. but I am not able to configure the options of the JitsiMeetView.
I want to hide the chat icon and menu bar icon from the JistiMeetView.

Comment: Could you please provide more informations on what you have tried to do. Share your actual code

Comment: I am referring to this code and its same as it is
https://github.com/skrafft/react-native-jitsi-meet/blob/master/ExampleApp/App.js
In this Code when we render the JistiMeetView, in the UI there is by default chat icon and the menu option.
So I want to hide that by default options.

Comment: You should post another question if your precise issue is to hide chat icon and menu option, since you did not mention it on your question